# Apache Tomcat 8 not working. Throws HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

Tags: java, php, apache, tomcat, tomcat8

I am using Apache Tomcat 8 and I've JDK 1.7.

Tomcat starts running after I run "startup.bat". But when I try to run "`http://localhost:8080/`", it shows an error: "**HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp**"

Please help me to fix this.
[image]
[Click here to see the screenshot](http://tinypic.com/r/35in9fc/8)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IT'S WORKING!

What I did:

1. Opened command prompt using "Run as administrator"
2. Went to the "bin" directory of Tomcat folder.

   ```
   cd C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.3\bin'
   ```
3. Entered 'startup' to run 'startup.bat' and the server started
4. Opened a web browser entered `http://localhost:8080/` and it worked like charm.  This also started generating Tomcat log files too.

The only different thing I performed is "Run as administrator".

But I checked with Tomcat7 it did not require me to "Run as administrator" but it worked; not sure why

Comment: The server should have the user rights. E.g. in Linux the "bin" folder should be set for "rwx" for your normal user and not for root user .

Answer (score 0):

Check the lib folder of your tomcat installation. It must contain the JARs jasper-el.jar, jasper.jar, and jsp-api.jar. If they exist, maybe you should add Tomcat 8 in the Java Build Path for your project.

EDIT:

What you can do is to run shutdown.bat. Then look for a file called **catalina.out** in the logs folder of your tomcat installation. Open it in a text editor, delete all of its contents and save. Then try running startup.bat again. Next copy the contents of **catalina.out** and paste them here. This may help other people solve your problem.

Comment: All these jar files exists in the lib folder. 
How to "add Tomcat 8 in the Java Build Path for your project."?

Comment: Try creating a JAVA_HOME environment variable and assign it with a value of where your JDK 1.7 is located.

Comment: Let me try to give you more specifics:  


After configuring Tomcat8 I ran 'http://localhost:8080'.  Each time I refreshed the page it showed the following errors in sequence (each time i refreshed the page)  
[Screenshot 1]http://tinypic.com/r/9vhxja/8  
[Screenshot 2]http://tinypic.com/r/33dbaeh/8  
[Screenshot 3]http://tinypic.com/r/dpijia/8

Comment: JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME  already set properly.    
I tried using Tomcat7 and it works perfectly fine. BUT not Tomcat8 !

Comment: no not yet  but by default it should show a tomcat page right?  Which it is not showing.

Comment: I've added this code in a phptest.xml file inside \apache-tomcat-8.0.3\conf\Catalina\localhost folder   
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/phptest" docBase="C:\PHP\test" debug="0" privileged="true"></Context>' to access 'http://localhost:8080/phptest/'  But it still doesn't work :(

Comment: IT'S WORKING!   

What I did:  
1) Opened command prompt using "Run as administrator"  
2) Went to the "bin" directory of Tomcat folder. 'cd C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.3\bin'  
3) Entered 'startup' to run 'startup.bat' and the server started
4) Opened a favourite web browser entered `http://localhost:8080/` and it worked like charm  :)  This way it also generated Tomcat log files too.

The only different thing I performed is "Run as administrator". 

But I checked with Tomcat7 it did not require me to "Run as administrator" but it worked. 

WHY?

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same error attempting to reach the manager URL (actually, 404 then 500 after page refresh, each single time).  I thought it was `<SERVER_BASE_URL>/manager/`.  It turns out it was `<SERVER_BASE_URL>/manager/html`.

It’s worth mentioning it wouldn’t tell me I wasn’t using the right credentials either.

Answer (score -2):

Simple, A ClassNotFoundException throws when some where a class that is used in the code is missing.

EG : If it is for servlet, then it means something servlet api that is regularly available to tomcat is now missing for some reason.

quite possibly the servlet-api.jar file in tomcat's lib folder (maybe other jar files in the tomcat lib folder) have become corrupted or removed.

Find it, you'll fix that.

Comment: I agree. But the jar files exists in the lib folder. What should I try next?